# Automapper using ViewModel property in Sql

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, enums, automapper

Having an issue with an `enum` with `automapper`

I have a EF Data Set using an `enum` as one of the property's and a view model to display this on a Grid with the `enum` and a `ToString` to show the text value of the `enum`

I am using `AutoMapper` to map the EF class to the ViewModel class but when loading the data I get an error

> System.NotSupportedException: 'The specified type member
>   'DataTableTypeDisplay' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only
>   initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are
>   supported.

I have tried to add Ignore options to the config for the `DataTableTypeDisplay` and no change.

Works fine if I remove this property but then Grid only show `int` value for `Enum`

using `AutoMapper v7.0.1`

Class File

```
public class ClassName
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ClassNameId { get; set; }

    public DataTableType DataTableType { get; set; }
…
```

View Model

```
public class ClassNameGridViewModel : ChangeControlBase
{
    public Guid? ClassNameId { get; set; }

    public DataTableType DataTableType { get; set; } = DataTableType.None;

    [NotMapped]
    public string DataTableTypeDisplay
    {
        get { return DataTableType.ToString(); }
    }
…
```

AutoMapper Config

```
public ClassNameGridViewModelProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<NS.ClassName, NS.ClassNameGridViewModel>();

        CreateMap<NS.ClassNameGridViewModel, NS.ClassName>();
    }
```

Enum

```
public enum DataTableType
{
    None = 0,
    Type1 = 1,
    Type2 = 2,
    Type3 = 3,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Automapper does not use the `[NotMapped]` attribute. It does have an `[IgnoreMap]` attribute, but this means adding the Automapper reference to your affected entities. Alternatively when you configure your mappings for Entity -> VM:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ClassName, ClassNameGridViewModel>()
.ForMember(vm => vm.DataTableTypeDisplay, opts => opts.Ignore())
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added this but I still get the same error. Also tried the [IgnoreMap] attribute, it seems like its ignoring my mapping config.

Comment: Can you add the exact EF linq expression that is raising the error?

Comment: Ok, thanks you pointed me in the right direction, this is not an Automapper error. I looked at the SQL and its fine, I'm also using Telerik DataSource this seems to be having an affect on the Query also, I will do more digging and find the issue

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out not to be Automapper that worked as expected, I am also using a Telerik DataSource Request which adds sorts, filters grouping and paging to the underlying query as the DataTableTypeDisplay column doesn't exist in the SQL table this is causing the error.

My current solution is to move the `enum` to a table in the database and map via a navigation property.